# Roots of an equation form an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Four roots of this equation:

$x^4+px^2+q=0$

form another equation, which ties p and q. What is the another equation?

Well, I've been sitting on it for some while and I don't really get what it means for roots to form an equation. I thought it was about to create an equation the roots of which were the roots of $x^4+px^2+q=0$, but couldn't get much out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints;

1)$$u:=x^2 \iff u^2+pu+q=0$$

2) [Vieta's quadratic formulas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#Example)